# Find $ \lim\limits_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to0\,\,}}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve the following limit:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to0\,\,}}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}
&=
\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to0\,\,}}\left\{\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\;\right]^\frac{x^2}{x+y}\right\}^\frac{1}{x}\\
&=
\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to0\,\,}} e\cdot\frac{x}{x+y}\\
&=e
\end{align*}
[Paint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJl1K.jpg)

So, this is the solution I got. Is everything correct?

---

.....And something else. I really don't have a clue about this one:

$$
\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to\infty}}\frac{\exp\left\{-\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right\}}{x^4+y^4}.$$
[Paint2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awu6w.jpg)

Can you guys help me find a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but please, don't every use paint again. Review the edit. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Also, I used $\exp$ instead of $e$ for legibility. As Jan writes $\exp (x) = e^x$.

Comment: Thanks probablyme! Do you have any idea on the second limit?

Comment: It's ok haha. I wish I didn't have to do calculus too

Comment: What does $\lim\limits_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to0\,\,}}$ mean?

Comment: it is a limit of two variables

Comment: I can see that, but what kind of limit is it? Do you let $x\to \infty$ first, then let $y\to 0?$

Comment: Or do you follow the curve $\left(x,\frac1x\right)$ as $x\to \infty$? Or the curve $(-\ln\lvert y\rvert, y)$ as $y\to 0$ ? Limit of two variables makes sense when $(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)$ **a point of $\Bbb R^2$**. But "$(0,\infty)$" is not.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\lim_{y\to0}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}\right]\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\lim_{y\to0}\left[\exp\left[\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{x+y}}\right)\right]\right]\right]=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\lim_{y\to0}\left[\exp\left[\frac{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x+y}\right]\right]\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\exp\left[\lim_{y\to0}\frac{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x+y}\right]\right]=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x+0}\right]=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x}\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1}\right]=\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]=$$

---

Applying l'Hôpital's rule, to get:

---

$$\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right]=\exp\left[\frac{1}{1+0}\right]=\exp\left[1\right]=e^1=e$$

Comment: Thanks Jan, but I think I haven't learnt this method yet. I don't know what exp is, so I am not allowed to use it

Comment: @snitchben $\exp(x)=e^x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the second one: The expression is $\le 1/(x^4+y^4).$

Comment: Thanks zhw., but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If $a\ge 0,$ then $e^{-a}\le 1.$ Also, please answer my question above.